# Issues reading Modbus RTU holding registers. Response is the same as request

Tags: python-3.x, beagleboneblack, modbus, rs485, pymodbus

I wrote a program using python3.8.2 and pymodbus on a beaglebone to do modbus RTU communication via RS485. I am using a MAX13487E on a cape connected to UART1 to drive the RS485 (p9_24, p9_26). The beaglebone is the master.

For my purposes I only require to use FC3 (read holding) and FC6 (write holding). I have been able to write with no issue. However, I am unable to read. Pymodbus returns an exception `ModbusIOException('No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response', 4).`

Using pymodbus REPL to debug, I found that the replies received were the same as the requests sent, only shorter as the master is expecting a shorter response. *i.e.*

```
SEND: 0x32 0x3 0x1 0x30 0x0 0x1 0x80 0x3a
RECV: 0x32 0x3 0x1 0x30 0x0 0x1 0x80
```

I have been able to poll this same slave in the past using other masters (e.g. diagslave-modpoll for windows) with no problems.

What would be the reason this would be happening? If anyone has any experience working with the MAX13487E transceiver, would you be able to aid in its use?

Answer (score 0):

I found an attribute of ModbusRTUClient() included in the kwargs** called "handle_local_reflection". Setting that to true seemed to solve the problem. I didn't bother looking into how it works, I'm just happy that it does.

However, if I was doing multiple requests in succession in only worked for the first one. Adding a small delay `time.sleep(0.05)` between requests made it all more stable.

Comment: On a Modbus RTU connection you can't send a new request until the reply for the previous one is received.   A serial connection has no means to avoid collisions. A strict request->reply->request-> reply ... order must be used.

Comment: @from56 I just assumed the pymodbus library would just handle that and would block until the transaction was complete. I might be mistaken. I am using the synchronous client.